# ¿Cómo hago peticiones a una api hasta que no me devuelva nada? NODEJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

estoy intentando extraer datos de una api, me devuelve una lista de usuarios con toda la información de ellos, pero está limitada por 100 usuarios por página, entonces cada vez que obtengo los datos, tengo que sumar una página, hay alguna forma de hacer un bucle y que la api no me de error por el rateLimit? (2 peticiones por segundo), adjunto el código y muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
app.get("/check/users", (req, res, next) => {
            if (req.originalUrl.startsWith("/404")) {
                return error();
            }
            let totalUsersArray = [];
            let pageNumber = 1;

            const options = {
                method: "GET",
                url: `xxx/xxx/xxx/campus/37/users?page[size]=100&page[number]=${pageNumber}`,
                headers: {  Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BEARER_TOKEN}` }
            }
            request(options, async (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    throw new Error(error);
                }
                else {
                    const arrayUsers = JSON.parse(body);
                    arrayUsers.forEach(async (user) => {
                        totalUsersArray.push(user.login);
                    });
                }
                console.log(totalUsersArray);
                res.send(totalUsersArray);
            });
        });
```

Tocando un poco he intentado algo como esto, pero todavía falla, y no me devuelve nada en ningún momento:

```
while (pageNumber != null) {
                const options = {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/campus/37/users?page[size]=100&page[number]=${pageNumber}`,
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BEARER_TOKEN}` }
                }
                    request(options, async (error, response, body) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw new Error(error);
                    }
                    else {
                        const arrayUsers = JSON.parse(body);
                        arrayUsers.forEach(async (user) => {
                            totalUsersArray.push(user.login);
                        });
                    }
                    console.log("here")
                    if (body == "[]") {
                        pageNumber = null;
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(pageNumber);
                        pageNumber++;
                    }
                });
            }
            console.log(totalUsersArray);
            res.send(totalUsersArray);
        });
```

Comment: En general, cuando hay un "Rate Limit",  el mismo es por usuario. De manera que la forma de saltarse ese limite sería hacer los requests con distintos usuarios.

Comment: Vale, entiendo lo que dices, pero sólo puedo usar 1 usuario, crees que exista alguna forma de meter en un while la petición y que se espere para ir haciendo las otras peticiones?, esto no lo haré mucho, sólo cuando se inicie él servidor de forma que la lista total de usuarios ya quede pre-cargada. @Emeeus

Comment: No es recomendable, pero puedes usar un temporizador (`setTimeout`) antes de ejecutar la siguiente petición. Ayudaría mucho saber para qué quieres obtener todo el listado si la API está pensada para funcionar con paginación.

Comment: Quiero todo el listado porqué tengo un Input donde introducen un nombre de usuario, y necesito comparar a ver si el usuario existe, para ello necesito toda la lista. @Triby

Comment: ¿La API no te da opción de búsqueda?

Comment: @Triby , no tiene esa opción

Comment: Eso es un gran problema de diseño y solo te deja la opción de retrasar cada petición para "sacarle la vuelta" al límite de peticiones y no creo que que sea una buena opción porque la respuesta final podría tardar mucho. Podrías crear un caché y tratar de sincronizarlo eventualmente.

Comment: @Triby Lo he solucionado, pero tengo problema con la repetición de valores, alguna idea de que puede ser?

Answer (score 0):

He logrado solucionarlo de la siguiente forma, pero sigo teniendo un problema, y es que me repite información en el array, por eso luego hago un filterByUniq, lo cual retrasa aún más la petición.

```
app.get("/check/users", (req, res, next) => {
            if (req.originalUrl.startsWith("/404")) {
                return error();
            }
            let totalUsersArray = [];
            let pageNumber = 1;
            getUsers();

            async function getUsers() {
                let options = {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/campus/37/users?page[size]=100&page[number]=${pageNumber}`,
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.BEARER_TOKEN}` }
                }
                request(options, async (error, response, body) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw new Error(error);
                    }
                    else if (body == "[]") {
                        pageNumber = 0;
                        let unique = totalUsersArray.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
                        let beautyData = beautify(JSON.stringify(unique), { indent_size: 4, space_in_empty_paren: true });
                        fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve("public/downloads", "total_users.json"), `${beautyData}`);
                        res.send(unique);
                    }
                    else {
                        const arrayUsers = JSON.parse(body);
                        await arrayUsers.forEach(async (user) => {
                            totalUsersArray.push(user.login);
                        });
                        pageNumber++;
                        await getUsers();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```